# Nested lambda calls in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

When nesting lambda calls in Kotlin, how can I unambiguously refer to child's and parent's `it` element? For instance:

```
data class Course(var weekday: Int, var time: Int, var duration: Int)
var list1 = mutableListOf<Course>()
var list2 = mutableListOf<Course>()
// populate list1 and list2
// exclude any element from list1 if it has the same time and weekday as any element from list2
list1.filter { list2.none{it.weekday == it.weekday && it.time == it.time} }
```

Comment: In your example code, `var (list1,list2) = ArrayList<Course>()` does not create two lists but attempts to [destructure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) an empty `ArrayList<Course>` into two `Course` instances which would fail at run-time as it is empty. The following would work though: `val list1 = mutableListOf<Course>(); val list2 = mutableListOf<Course>()`

Comment: Thanks, editted. But is there a way to declare any 2 vars and assign them the same value?

Comment: Not any way that I would recommend. :-) Feel free to search StackOverflow and add the question if it isn't already out there.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`it` always refers to the innermost lambda's parameter, to access outer ones, you have to name them. For example:

```
list1.filter { a -> list2.none { b -> a.weekday == b.weekday && a.time == b.time} }
```

(You could leave the inner one as `it`, but it's a bit nicer if you name that too, in my opinion.)

**Edit:** @mfulton26 linked the relevant documentation below, see that for more details.

Comment: You might add links to the relevant documentation. Namely [Higher-Order Functions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions) and [`it`: implicit name of a single parameter](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter).

Comment: You can also use [destructuring in Lambdas (since 1.1)](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-in-lambdas-since-11). e.g.: `list1.filter { (weekday1, time1) -> list2.none { (weekday2, time2) -> weekday1 == weekday2 && time1 == time2 } }`.