# Kotlin Multiple Layer it Reference

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

How do you reference the second layer "it" from the third layer without creating a new val/var?  I know you can do val mydata = it and then do mydata.id.toString()  I was just wondering is there something in Kotlin that can let me reference an it from a higher level?

```
data.arrayresults.forEach {
    val result = it

    result.myData.let {
        val itemView - inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout)

        itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            // the it references the view but I want it to reference the result.myData
            SomeActivity.startActivity(context, it.id.toString())
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on this answer, I would say no: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43042442/2259854

Comment: [No, and you shouldn't use nested `it`s anyway](https://youtu.be/ihdEjDoXOgc?t=17m45s).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the `it` symbol always references the innermost implicit single lambda parameter.

To resolve this, and also to improve the code readability, use [named lambda parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) every time when you have nested lambdas with parameters, as suggested in the [Coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#lambdas):

```
data.arrayresults.forEach { result ->    
    result.myData.let { myData ->
        val itemView - inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout)

        itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->

            // the it references the view but I want it to reference the result.myData
            SomeActivity.startActivity(context, myData.id.toString())
        })
    }
}
```